# Checking that a string matches one regex and doesn't match another

Tags: python, regex

I'm using `pylint` and `flake8` to control the code quality. However I am in check-mate position, where styling one does not suit the `pylint` or `flake8`:

```
if (not re.search(regexp, summary) and
    not re.search(regexp2, summary)):                   
    return False
```

Output from `flake8`:

```
visually indented line with same indent as next logical line [E129]
```

Moving return is not helping, the previous error still occurs and there is new one thrown by `pylint`:

```
if (not re.search(regexp, summary) and
    not re.search(regexp2, summary)):                   
        return False
```

Output from `pylint`:

```
[bad-indentation] Bad indentation. Found 8 spaces, expected 4
```

Comment: What are the two regular expressions? Please provide full context for your question.

Answer (score 4):

Per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you can (*"Acceptable options in this situation include, but are not limited to..."*) further indent the second line of the condition:

> ```
> # Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
> if (this_is_one_thing
>         and that_is_another_thing):
>     do_something()
> ```

The difference is that indentation in the continuation lines is purely stylistic, whereas indentation of the next code block has semantic meaning. In your case:

```
if (not re.search(regexp, summary)
        and not re.search(regexp2, summary)):                   
    return False
```

Note I have moved the `and` per the same guidance.

Comment: In addition: I'd also consider to move that complex condition into a separate function. There are good chances that the purpose of a long wall of text isn't immediately obvious

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that would be another option, although if the regexes have sensible names I think a two-part conditional is OK. You don't want to end up writing `if is_foo_and_bar(thing):` when `if is_foo(thing) and is_bar(thing):` is just as readable!

Comment: I agree but it won't then be probably long enough to need to split. Also `is_foo_and_bar(thing)` might be `is_buz(thing)` (because `foo` and `bar` together mean something else), in that case a local variable or a function will definitely clarify. Anyway, it's just another option to consider, not The Way to Go